# Issue with firebase implementation

Tags: javascript, firebase

```
   import firebase from "firebase/compat/app"
    import "firebase/compat/auth"
    
    const app = firebase.initializeApp = ({
        apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
        authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
        projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
        databaseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
        storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
        messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
        appId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID
      })
    
      export const auth = app.auth()
      export default app
```

Issue:
TypeError: app.auth is not a function. I want to be able to implement firebase authentication and am getting the above error. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
    import firebase from "firebase/compat/app"
    import "firebase/compat/auth"
    
    const app = firebase.initializeApp({
        apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
        authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
        projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
        databaseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
        storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
        messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
        appId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID
      })
    
      export const auth = app.auth()
      export default app
```

firebase.initializeApp is a function and it accepts the object as argument.

Comment: You rock! Worked like a charm!